# Encrypt multiple partitions (different OS)

Tags: encryption, windows, debian

I have a disk with multiple partitions:

- Windows 7 (one partition )
- Debian 8.2 (3 partitions : root `/` + `/home` + `swap`)

I'm using Grub 2 for dual booting. I want to know the best way to encrypt all of the data on my disk. Is it possible to encrypt everything with one procedure, or should I encrypt each OS separately.

If I need to encrypt each OS, the procedure should be different on each OS, right? In this case what are the best encryption programs?

I can reinstall and re-partition everything if it'll help the process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to encrypt separately for each system

On **Windows**: [Bitlocker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BitLocker) is built-in and easiest to use. An alternative is [Veracrypt](http://www.veracrypt.fr/en/Home.html).

On **Linux**: The traditional approach is to use [dm-crypt](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Disk_encryption).

It is technically possible to have a separate, encrypted partition used by both systems (when dual booting) if it is encrypted by portable technologies. The now-defunct Truecrypt could do that, Veracrypt should be able too (as it is a fork) but I have not tested that.

Comment: Thanks, can I have more information about how to use Veracrypt as a 'portable technologie' ?